# Queue method or individual db connection?

Tags: java, sockets, optimization, message-queue

I have socket connection which will send data into a queue via `databaseQueue.add(message);`. Next the the `DatabaseProcessor` class which is started as thread during the start where single database connection will be made. The connection will keep taking the message via `databaseQueue.take();` and process. The good part about this part everything is that just one database connection is made. The problem arises when suddenly there is a surge of data. So another method is that for each data received I will open and close method. So based your experiences for heavy loads which is the best way to go here?

Some snippet of my codes.

```
class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
    ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
      this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
    }


      // gets data from an inbound connection and queues it for databse update

      public void run() {
          databaseQueue.add(message); // put to db queue

       }
}
class DatabaseProcessor implements Runnable {
public void run()
      {
         // open database connection
         createConnection();
             while (true) 
             {
                  message = databaseQueue.take(); // keep taking message from the queue add by connectionhandler and here I will have a number of queries to run in terms of select,insert and updates.
                  }
        }

void createConnection()
 {
    System.out.println("Crerate Connection");
    connCreated = new Date();
    try 
     {
    dbconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1?"+"user=user1&password=*******");
    dbconn.setAutoCommit(false);

     }
     catch(Throwable ex)
     {
       ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
     }

 }
}

public void main()
{
new Thread(new DatabaseProcessor()).start(); //calls the DatabaseProcessor
//initiate the socket 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are managing a client-server Socket connection in which you send and receive message through a queue. If I also got it right, you are creating a thread for each new message on the queue.

Considering that there will be plenty of messages being sent and read I recommend you to declare your method(s) in your threads [Synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) so that you won't need to open and close streaming each time a data is received (refer to your second approach here). Synchronized Methods are usually the best way to handle surge of common data which can be modified by threads at the same time.

Comment: no I do not create new thread for each new message I create one thread via the main that remains for ever to keep receiving message and pass to another separate thread dealing with db stuff. So do I still need synchronized

Answer (score 0):

You can use connection pooling to get the best of both worlds: you are not limited to a single thread, and you also do not need to open connections for each request. Have a look at [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/).

Comment: so is it dangerous to use my current method of just one connection in the thread is it?

Comment: No there is nothing dangerous about it, but if you use just one connection, your throughput will be limited (depending on your needs).

Comment: I have added some snippet of codes on how I am doing it. What about creating more database processor thread will that be helpful?? Based on my current setting what do you suggest to change?

Comment: You could do that too - the actual settings will depend on how fast you receive messages on the socket vs. how long it takes to update the database.

Comment: that will require some experiments rite. how should I conduct the experiment to get to the best make up for all the test cases.

Comment: If you're not sure yet, you should just go with some default settings now and optimize it later if you think you are having issues.

Comment: I tried for now to just increase one extra thread but it introduce me another problem is that at times my sequence of data updates into the db goes out why before 2 processing is done parallel.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is fine. Except you can create an a DB pool using c3pO. Also use threadPool executor for miantaining your thread pool.

Comment: when you say the approach is fine then in my database processor now I call one function to create one single connection so how to create connection pool in that ?

Comment: I have added snippet of my codes how do you suggest to change it into connection pooling?